# How update WildFly 10.1.0Final Apache Artemis 1.1.0 to Apache Artemis 1.3

Tags: websocket, stomp, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

I have installed WildFly 10.1.0.Final I I created a Stomp over Websocket client to in Javascript to connect directly to a topic in Artemis.

I connect an subscrite two clients but when I close or unscribe one of the two clients, the others spot recive messages.

I found a mail-list that have exactly discribing the same problem.

http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/STOMP-server-quits-sending-to-all-subscribers-when-one-client-disconnects-td4713980.html

One user called "johndament" mention that the auto creation feature fixes this error (in v1.3). Then "Ed Kaltenbach" solve the problem updating the ActiveMQ artemimis version from v1.1.0 that is shipped with wildFly 10.1.0.Final to v1.3

Can helpme to update the version and recommendations?

[image: WildFly Artemis 1.1.0]

These are the files after download and unzip ActiveMQ 1.3 from the official site:

[image: ActiveMQ Artemis 1.3]

Answer (score 1):

The following instructions work for updating to Artemis 1.3.
Note that I also tried this for Artemis 1.5, this did NOT work....

1) copy apache-artemis-1.3.0/bin/lib/* to wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\activemq\artemis\main\lib (replace the existing *.so files)

2) copy all Jars from apache-artemis-1.3.0/lib to the corresponding subdirectory in wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\activemq\artemis. Copy all files to the location where you find a Jar file with the same name but different version. Remove the old Jar files, and make sure you also change the version numbers in the respective module.xml.

Some files from apache-artemis-1.3.0/lib don't have a corresponding file in wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\activemq\artemis. You can ignore these files.