# Websockets / STOMP with ActiveMQ Artemis on Wildfly 10 not working

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

I am implementing a WebSockets application using Spring WebSockets.

As a STOMP broker, I want to use Wildfly's Artemis (Active MQ).

I did the following configuration in standalone-full.xml:

- Adding the following acceptor:

  ```
  <acceptor name="stomp-acceptor"
      factory-class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory">
      <param name="protocols" value="STOMP" />
      <param name="port" value="61613" />
  </acceptor>
  ```
- add a new application user guest/guest to application-users.properties using add-user.bat
- add the following StompConfiguration (abbreviated):

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
  public class StompConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
      @Override
      public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
          registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
      }

      @Override
      public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
          config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
              config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue").setRelayHost("localhost").setRelayPort(61613)
              .setClientLogin("guest").setClientPasscode("guest");
          }
      }
  ```

This seems to work well at startup:

> 16:57:13,890 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221020: Started Acceptor at
>   localhost:61613 for protocols [STOMP] 16:57:13,892 INFO 
>   [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 64) AMQ221007: Server is now live

However, wenn I send the first message using Spring's SimpMessagingTemplate:

```
template.convertAndSend(topic, payload);
```

I get the error

> ERROR
>   [org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler]
>   (reactor-tcp-io-1) Received ERROR {message=[AMQ339001: Destination
>   does not exist: /topic/abc/12345/xyz]}
>   session=*system*

Using Stomp, it should not be necessary to create a topic beforehand. How can I tell Artemis to create it automatically?

Comment: it is advisable to add the "host" parameter to the stomp-acceptor. Otherwise it cannot be accessed from another host, as the default for "host" is localhost:  <param name="host" value="10.xx.yyy.zzz,localhost"/> (replace with your server's IP address)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, 2 problems caused this error message:

1)
The first problem was that the name of the topic did *not* start with "jms.topic", but Artemis seems to expect that (for whatever reason...).

By changing the code to

```
template.convertAndSend("jms.topic." + topic, payload);
```

I could resolve the problem.

Note that it was also necessary to change the StompBrokerRelay configuration:

```
 config.enableStompBrokerRelay("jms.topic")
```

2) The application now worked, but when I had several clients and one unsubscribed from the topic, the error reappeared again. This error and its solution (an upgrade to Artemis 1.3) is described here: [How update WildFly 10.1.0Final Apache Artemis 1.1.0 to Apache Artemis 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152226/how-update-wildfly-10-1-0final-apache-artemis-1-1-0-to-apache-artemis-1-3/42390389#42390389)